# Xpath that does not contain a child appium

Tags: android, xpath, appium

I'm new with appium.
I have a list of elements inside my screen that are in relatives layouts
but the list contain different types of elements and I want to access just the one with a specific type of them.

For example :
A publicity will look like this

- [Relative layout]

  - [View]

    - [Web view]

A normal article will have this

- [Relative layout]

  - [View id=view_id]
  - [ImageView id=picture_id]
  - [TextView id=title_id]

A subrscriber article will have this

- [Relative layout]

  - [View id=view_id]
  - [ImageView id=picture_id]
  - [ImageView id=subscriber_id]
  - [TextView id=title_id]

How do I select only the "normal" articles ?

I tried this
          `List<WebElement> list = el.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[not(.//android.widget.ImageView)]"));`

But didn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you tried to use `not(.//android.widget.ImageView)`, because *normal article*, as explained, contains an `ImageView`. Instead, maybe you want to find `RelativeLayout` that contains only one `ImageView`.

In XPath, you can use `count()` to filter element that contains certain number of descendant elements, for example :

```
//android.widget.RelativeLayout[count(.//android.widget.ImageView) = 1]
```

Comment: My first try was to see if the "not" function worked event without the result i was searching for but I couldn't manage to make it work

By trying your solution I found out that if you use a function like count(), you have to make your research direclty on the driver and not on an element maybe it was also the reason the "not" didn't worked

anyway thanks a lot !